# Notify Visual Studio of code called through reflection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection, roslyn

**Context:**

The environment I work in has a lot of 'magic' methods and fields that are called or set through reflection from external code. Something may have an attribute that means it will be set to a non-default value, but Visual Studio still doesn't see that aspect and "helpfully" provides the warning.

Since these are handled using attributes and specifically named methods, ideally I'd like to provide VS with additional information so that it knows that it's called or set, without me having to manually suppress each warning.

I've looked into writing a Roslyn analyzer, but from what I can tell I can only add additional warnings, not modify existing warnings/reference count.

**Examples:**

`[MyCmpGet] private Component comp`

"Field is never assigned to and will always have its default value null"

However the field is assigned through reflection due to the annotation.

```
[HarmonyPatch]
class Patch
{
     static void Postfix() {}
}
```

"Private member is unused"
"0 references"

However the method is called through reflection, due to the annotation on the class, and the method having a specific name.

**Question:**

What is the best way to let visual studio know that these fields are being set, and that these methods are being referenced?  Preferably without requiring me to take manual actions for each one, and without adding anything additional to the example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a `DiagnosticSuppressor` analyzer. The default analyzer templates should produce a nuget package that you can include in all projects where you want to suppress this warning.

here is and example of what a diagnostic suppressor looks like at its most basic form:

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Immutable;

[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public sealed class DiagnosticSuppressorForAssignmentWarnings : DiagnosticSuppressor {
    public SuppressionDescriptor SuppressionDescriptor => new SuppressionDescriptor(
        id: "SPR0001", // Id for this analyzer suppressor (You should come up with a unique name for yours)
        suppressedDiagnosticId: "CS0649", // The warning that we may want to suppress
        justification: "This is ok because it is assigned via reflection");

    public override ImmutableArray<SuppressionDescriptor> SupportedSuppressions
        // You can pass in multiple suppression descriptors to have this suppress multiple types of warnings
        => ImmutableArray.Create(SuppressionDescriptor);

    public override void ReportSuppressions(SuppressionAnalysisContext context) {
        foreach (var diagnostic in context.ReportedDiagnostics) {
            // The parsed syntax tree of the file that this warning comes from
            var syntaxTree = diagnostic.Location.SourceTree;
            // The syntax Node that the warning was reported for
            var nodeWithWarning = syntaxTree.GetRoot().FindNode(diagnostic.Location.SourceSpan);
            // A semantic model that can answer questions like 'does this attribute inherit from this type' etc.
            var semanticModel = context.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);

            // You can do additional analysis of the source to ensure this is something 
            // that is semantically safe to suppress (like check for an attribute)

            context.ReportSuppression(Suppression.Create(SuppressionDescriptor, diagnostic));
        }
    }
}
```

For more documentation on how to write analyzers I would take a look at [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/) blog post or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019) documentation

Comment: Should this work on its own, or are there other pieces I'm missing?  I can get normal analyzers to work, but I can't get suppression to work - the code doesn't even seem to be executing and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? suppression analyzers are a new feature

Comment: I'm using VS2019.  I had to update the nuget packages from the template project to even get access to Suppression stuff, but I got that working and compiling.

The `SupportedSuppressions` property gets called multiple times (tested with breakpoints), but the code never enters the `ReportSuppressions` method.

Comment: I believe I finally figured it out.  Testing analyzers using the VSIX does not work for build warnings.  Manually installing the package to my project appears to work as expected.

Comment: How do you install this into a CSharpCompilation object?

Comment: I tried `compiler = (CSharpCompilation)compiler.WithAnalyzers(ImmutableArray.Create(new DiagnosticAnalyzer[] {new DiagnosticSuppressorCS0626(), new DiagnosticSuppressorCS0227()})).Compilation; ` but that didn't work.